# Server error after updating Jspool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm working with React.NET, i recently updated those nugets:

[image]

And now i receive this error :

```
Method not found: 'JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.IJsEngine JSPool.IJsPool.GetEngine(System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>)'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.IJsEngine JSPool.IJsPool.GetEngine(System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>)'.
```

Stack trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.IJsEngine JSPool.IJsPool.GetEngine(System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>)'.]
   React.JavaScriptEngineFactory.GetEngine() +0
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +741
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +430
   React.ReactEnvironment.EnsureUserScriptsLoaded() +40
   React.ReactEnvironment.CreateComponent(String componentName, T props, String containerId, Boolean clientOnly) +43
```

Google didn't helped much, maby you can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScriptEnginerSwitch 2.0 is not supported yet: https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/319

and

https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/306

You will need to revert back to the previous version of those packages to get things working.

Comment: Thanks for the informaion!